# Javascript variables not accessible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that will be triggered on click (using jQuery).

I don't understand why the following doesn't work and shows *undefined*.

```
var testFunc = function(event) {
    var data     = event.data;
    var category = data.category;
    var action   = data.action;
    var label    = data.label;

    console.debug(data);
    // prints:
    // {'category': 'CCC', 'action': 'AAA', 'label': 'LLL'}

    console.debug(data.category);
    // prints: undefined

    console.debug(category);
    // prints: undefined

    console.debug(data[category]);
    // prints: undefined
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test').on('click', function() {
        var jsonData;
        try {
            jsonData = JSON.parse($(this).data('test'));
        }
        catch (e) {
            // I guess here is the problem:
            jsonData = $(this).data('test');
            // ..but why JSON.parse doesn't work
        }

        try {
            testFunc({ data: jsonData });
        } catch (e) {
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="about:blank" target="_blank" class="test"
   data-test="{'category': 'CCC'}">click event triggered here</a>
```

How to access event.data.category ?

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ytqp45wj/

Comment: Can you repro in a fiddle?

Comment: what is the `typeof` data?

Comment: Is data a plain object, or some structure that implements toString differently ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.data` is a string in your fiddle.

That's because your JSON in the `data-test` field is not valid.
So you pass into the exception handler when parsing it, and you use the String itself.

(Seems like you can not use single quotes in JSON, according to http://jsonlint.com/)

As pointed elsewhere, you can use double quotes inside your data attribute to fix things.

Note that the `data[category]` would not work anyway, so you still get `undefined` for that.

Comment: Tricky ! Solved it by changing the quotes like  `data-test='{"json":"val"}'`

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON data isn't formatted correctly. You need to use double quotes for the key values.

```
<a href="about:blank" target="_blank" class="test" data-test='{"category": "CCC", "action": "AAA", "label": "LLL"}'>click event triggered here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To access nested object properties use `[]` notation, for example:

```
event['data']['category']
```

Comment: There is no reason why you should have to use bracket notation instead of dot notation unless there are spaces in the var name

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';

var event = {data:{
     category: 'CCC', 
     action:'AAA', 
     label: 'LLL'
}};


var testFunc = function(event) {
    var data = event['data'];
    var category = event['data']['category'];


    console.debug(data);
    console.debug(category);

    //get keys for every data entry
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key){
        console.log(key, data[key]);
    });
};

testFunc(event);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/felixcriv/L8df71d2/)

You need to have a valid JSON object so you need to access to it using JSON notation.

Comment: I made an ammed to my post.